# eloquent join with empty subquery

Tags: eloquent, subquery

I have a table with columns called 'id', 'sport_id', 'date' and others less relevant to the problem.

I'm trying to find all fields in the rows that have the most recent dates, grouped by a particular column (list of sports with the last time they were played). A straight query doesn't work because it says 'id' is a non-aggregated column, but if I include it in GROUP BY, I end up with the entire table. In straight MySQL I can get around this by doing the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM activities AS a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT sport_id, MAX(date) AS date 
        FROM activities 
        GROUP BY sport_id
    ) AS r ON r.sport_id=a.sport_id
    WHERE r.date=a.date
```

This works fine whether the table has data or not.

I tried to convert this to an eloquent model like this:

```
$recent = Activity::orderBy('date', 'desc')->groupBy('sport_id')->select('sport_id', \DB::raw('MAX(date) as date'))->get();
$activity = Activity::joinSub($recent, 'recent', function ($join) {
    $join->on('recent.sport_id', '=', 'activity.sport_id')
        ->where('recent.date', '=', 'activity.date');
})->get();
```

Unfortunately, if the table is empty it returns

```
A subquery must be a query builder instance, a Closure, or a string.
```

I can solve this in php, but it will be ugly.

Has anyone had this problem before? Any advice on how I can deal with it in Eloquent?

To give this context, I eventually want to create a list of sports with the last time they were played, so I want to use the results of this query as a subquery itself. Perhaps there's a better way of doing this from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made the left join query correctly, but you should not call `get()` on it as you need your query builder object. When you call `get()`, the query builder performs its query and make your result as a laravel query collection instance. This is why you get such an error.

Additionally, you should write your second part of `where()` condition in `\DB::raw()` to preserve table reference. Also, I declared type of sub join as `left`.

Something like below code may help you, I've named `activities` table name for `Activity` model.

```php
$lj = Activity::query()
    ->groupBy('sport_id')
    ->select('sport_id', DB::raw('MAX(date) sub_max_date'));
$q = Activity::query()
    ->joinSub($lj,'t1','t1.sport_id','=','activities.sport_id', 'left')
    ->where('t1.sub_max_date', DB::raw('activities.date'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: If you have  minute, can you explain (or point me to an explanation) of why the DB::raw is necessary? Without it, I get an error 'General error: 1525 Incorrect DATE value: 'activities.date'', but the accompanying generated query works perfectly in the database itself.

Comment: You can debug your final query using `toSql()` method instead of `get()` at the end of your query builder.

Comment: Using `\DB::raw()` will place your query exactly you write in your code, without raw eloquent will put your value in the bindings property to prevent sql injection attack and it acts like a simple string, not a meaningful sql command.